# How to return a closure from an async function and assign it to useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I'm trying to return a function (closure) from a async function. So far, the way I have things `space` is always a promise and not a function, even though it should be a closure.

```js
// ...
    const [space, set_space] = React.useState(false);
    React.useEffect(
    () => {
        API.SERVER(query, PAGE_SIZE)
        .then(response => set_space(response));
    },
    [query]
    );

    React.useEffect(
    () => {
        console.log(space.constructor);
        if (space) {
        space(page)
            .then(response => set_titles(Array.from(response.data)));
        }
    },
    [space, page]
    );
// ...
```

#### API

```js
// ...
export default {
    SERVER:async function(search, width)
    {
        if (!search) {
        // return () => {};
        search = DEFAULT_QUERY;
    }
    const all = (await axios.get(SEARCH_URL + `?search=${search}`)).data;
    console.log(all);
    const pages = chunk(all, width);
    // function pager(results) {
    //     const dex = (results > width ? results / width : 0);
    //     const next = pages[dex];
    //     return axios.get(SEARCH_URL + `?fromids=${next}`);
    // }
    // return pager;
    return function(results) {
        const dex = (results > width ? results / width : 0);
        const next = pages[dex];
        return axios.get(SEARCH_URL + `?fromids=${next}`);
    };
    // return pager;
}
};
```

`space.constructor` says it's a Promise, but it should be a function that returns axios' Promise, not a Promise it's self. I can't really change the way the API is set up because I need to hold the index client side, then walk though it by changing space's parameter.

Comment: If you have a function that returns a value, then adding `async` automatically means it returns a `Promise` of that value.

Comment: I don't see how `space` could be a promise. It's either `false` or the `pager` function returned by `API.SERVER(…)` (confusingly also called `response`). Where and how did you log/inspect `space.constructor`? Are you getting some sort of error?

Comment: @Bergi It doesn't make sense to me either. Earlier, I have SERVER `return function(results) // ...` and with that style it didn't crash immediately, so I could call space.constructor in the second useEffect.

Comment: What do you mean by "crash"? What error are you getting?

Comment: @Bergi I get "space is not a function" and "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function." Crash, as in all the components disappear after load and it's just the html.style.background.

Comment: Well "*space is not a function*" is kind of expected since you initialise your state with `false`, which is not  function. But that has nothing to do with the closure returned from the async function.

Comment: Can you share a [mcve]? I still don't believe that `console.log(space.constructor);` would print `Promise` with the code you've posted

Comment: @Bergi I've tried initializing space with anonymous function and still, I get not a function. So, It dose seem to clear the first useEffect even with the crashing.

Comment: @Bergi with this last edit, it's now logging `Promise() { [native code] }` before it crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that `set_space` doesn't handle functions the same way as other values.

That's because React's state setters can take a callback that receives the previous state as an argument.

However, React has no way of differentiating between a callback and a value that happens to be a function. So, React will assume it's a callback and calls it, then set the state to contain its return value, another Promise.

To put the function itself into the state, you can create a callback that returns the function, like this:

```
API.SERVER(query, PAGE_SIZE)
.then(response => set_space(() => response));
```

Comment: I forgot that about useState. That makes me face palm. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnSmith Storing functions to state is not a common thing to do, so that's easy to miss...

Answer (score -1):

Hmmm... you just want a function that on call returns you the promise? What about `useCallback` then?

```js
const triggerAsync = React.useCallback(
    () => {
        return API.SERVER(query, PAGE_SIZE)
        .then(response => set_space(response))
    },
    [query]
    );
```

`triggerAsync` should then return a promise when you execute it